# PHP low performance on cURL and file_get_contents

Tags: php, performance, curl

I'm developing a PHP script which request some data from a REST API.

First i was using cURL for PHP, however it took too much time to send the request and get the response. Then i tried to use file_get_contents, but i got same results.

I say that PHP takes too much time (15 s) because, i consulted the same URL in the browser (chrome), in the same PC, and it took only 68ms.

I thought that it could be the environment, but my pc's spec is: Core i5-4570, 8GB RAM, W7x64, all updates, PHP 5.6.8 x32, Chrome v42 x64 with a lot of complements.  I'm running php on the embedded server.

I even tried to replace the server name in the URL for the IP server (avoid DNS look) but got the same results.

I set set_time_limit(3600) (php script time out), but i don't want the script to take so long to exec.

Any help please?

**EDIT:**
My code is:
PHP - cURL Time to exec (17.66 s)

```
$headers = array(
'Content-type: application/json',
'Authorization: Basic '.base64_encode($usr.':'.$pwd)
);

$opt = array(
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://url.example.com"
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $opt );
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

file_get_contents (13.63 s)

```
$headers = ['http' => ['header' => 'Authorization: Basic'.base64_encode($usr.':'.$pwd)] ];
$context = stream_context_create($headers);
file_get_contents("http://url.example.com", false, $context);
```

cURL command Line time to exec (12 s)

```
 curl -D- -u "user:pwd" -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://url.example.com -o out.json -v
```

Browser (45 - 63 ms)

I don't think the download size matters since it's about 1.2 KB.

I tried using gzip compression in cURL PHP but the output is encoded and don't know how to decode it. I'm really considering to use ASP.net and see the performance results.

Any configuration in PHP ini could help? like increasing the buffer size, default memory assigned?

Comment: Are you running the cURL command from a remote web server or from your own PC? If from a remote server, how long does it take you to `wget` (or similar) the same URL from that server? This is probably too broad a question.

Comment: cURL in PHP takes about 15-18 s, in command line (windows, my pc) takes about 12-15 s. I'm running it on my pc, windows.

Comment: Unlikely to do with php or curl. Something at the API, network or in pre/post precessing is sucking up the time

Comment: perhaps the issue is actually the target, not your code.

Comment: also if you want some help, post your code.

Comment: @Augwa there is my code. Mike, i don't think that is has something related to the API because, how in the same pc, it responds fast to the browser?

Comment: Is the browser sending all the same stuff or are you just going to the url and it's telling you unauthorized?

Comment: @Augwa, you are right. I was authenticated in the web page before consulting it. So when i just asked for the URL in the browser it sent the cookies and that's why it was so fast. I just tried to consult with an ajax request and it was terrible slow, even more to than PHP.

Comment: So the issue is the server is processing the request extremely slow, do you have control over the api or are you just a user of it?

Comment: @Augwa The issue is that the server is processing authentication really slow and i was authenticating on every request, so saving the cookie and using it for later, speeded up the process time. 
I don't have the control over the API since it's a proprietary software. Btw, when changed the authentication to cookies, i realized that login in the web page of the app is slow too. So the login takes time, make requests, not so much.

Comment: It should never take that long to authenticate, so it just seems like the API isn't scaleable at all. Unfortunately that is out of your control, so you can choose to keep using it, or if you have other options available consider them as well.